# How do I install htmldoc via cygwin?

Tags: make, cygwin

I've installed all packages with gcc in their title via cygwin on my PC along with FLTK and I ran `./configure` and `./configure ENTER` with no errors but now after running `make` I received the error:

```
Compiling http-addrlist.c...
http-addrlist.c: In function ‘httpAddrConnect’:
http-addrlist.c:59:5: error: ‘errno’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     errno = EINVAL;
     ^
http-addrlist.c:59:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
http-addrlist.c:59:13: error: ‘EINVAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     errno = EINVAL;
             ^
../Makedefs:76: recipe for target 'http-addrlist.o' failed
make[1]: *** [http-addrlist.o] Error 1
```

Comment: It looks to me like you don't have /usr/include/sys/errno.h on your system (that's what should define EINVAL). I don't know which cygwin package would provide that for you, though.

Answer (score -1):

It is the source code that is buggy; you have to debug it or use the https://github.com/fareoffice/htmldoc repository

If you were on Debian or Ubuntu you could even use then command
`apt-get install htmldoc`